# firebase cloudmessaging with python, can't auth - something wrong in token?

Tags: android, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to send a message on Android, using my Python code.

I'm coding some of it and I synchronize to my firebase database, but there seems to be a problem on SendMessage I think because of reference `push_service.notify_multiple_devices`

My Python:

```
from firebase import firebase
import json
import requests
import pyrebase 
from  pyfcm import FCMNotification
import sys

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication("https://test-3af6d.firebaseio.com/", None)
result = firebase.get("/users", None)
listToken = []
for k, v in result.items():
    listToken.append([k])
print(listToken)

push_service = FCMNotification(api_key="your_fcm_serverKey")

# Send to multiple devices by passing a list of ids.
registration_ids = listToken #["token1", "token2", ....]
message_title = "test FCM"
message_body = "hi"
message_sound = "default"

result = push_service.notify_multiple_devices(registration_ids=registration_ids, message_title=message_title, message_body=message_body)
```

this is my database pic
[image]

The results of my code:

```
 RESTART: C:/Users/snag/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/test_alert.py 
[['-LJN3hmc5131KtZB5pkx'], ['-LJN3oaTNwSfSDCHQYsF']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/snag/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/test_alert.py", line 26, in <module>
    result = push_service.notify_multiple_devices(registration_ids="-LJN3oaTNwSfSDCHQYsF", message_title=message_title, message_body=message_body)
  File "C:\Users\snag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyfcm\fcm.py", line 261, in notify_multiple_devices
    return self.parse_responses()
  File "C:\Users\snag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyfcm\baseapi.py", line 333, in parse_responses
    raise AuthenticationError("There was an error authenticating the sender account")
pyfcm.errors.AuthenticationError: There was an error authenticating the sender account
```

! - i'm brought 'users' token  [['-LJN3hmc5131KtZB5pkx'], ['-LJN3oaTNwSfSDCHQYsF']] as you can see on my result

Comment: i solve it myself.  pyfcm is only works on python2

Comment: there is no token field on database, i add [myToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();] at android studio and add token field